# Spoofing the user agent in Konqueror globally

Tags: linux, kde, konqueror

There's a browser identification menu for spoofing for specific sites, but how do I change the user agent for all sites?

Answer (score 0):

The default UA generation is hardcoded and you cannot adapt it without changing the source and recompiling.

However, depending on what you attempt to do the following work-around may be acceptable. The site/domain specific UA filter matches domain names part-wise. The consequence is that you can enter a top-level domain name and the specified UA works for all sites in that domain, e.g. enter `net` and pick `Opera` and you will spoof Opera on all sites whose domain name ends in `.net`.

Pick the most common TLD from the lists: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TLD http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CCTLD